# Best way to tear up half a concrete parking pad?

Tags: concrete, driveway, demolition

I have a concrete parking pad in my back yard (butts up to an alley) that is substantially larger than I need, and I'd like to reclaim some of that space for my yard.  To that end I'd like to tear up half the pad but leave the other half untouched, preferably with a semi nice edge to it.

So what's the best way to cleanly cut a concrete patio in half, so that I can tear up one side?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only way to do what you want to do is cut the concrete with a gear driven saw and masonry blade, then jack hammer out the rest of the concrete.  It really is not that difficult and you can rent all the equipment and do it in a day easy.  You don't have to cut all the way through the concrete, but at least 1/3 the way through. it should break off cleanly.  Even a small DeWalt hand held jack hammer will do the job, take a bit longer than a larger rental unit.

Comment: +1, also don't forget there're tractor-mounted jack hammers that offer higher performance than hand-held ones.

Comment: I'd wear a respirator for the cutting process. Cutting concrete makes a ton of dust, unless you're cutting wet.

Comment: Also, as sharptooth points out, you may want to look into a tractor-mounted jackhammer, especially if you're not a big guy. I've used a 60 lb. jackhammer for an 8 hour shift, and I would not want to do it again. Then again, I only weigh in at 120 lbs, so you may not have as rough a time with it.

Comment: Oh Ya. cutting concrete is a dusty, messy job. Up vote for the respirator.  BTW, hate to admit it, but I have laborers that I put on the jack hammer!! They love doing it.  I'm too old for that job. lol

Comment: Any concerns about footing issues?

Comment: Get a chalk line too for marking a nice straight line. My local tool hire place had the perfect concrete saw for this that you push along like a lawnmower, and a massive jackhammer. With those, it was actually kind of fun (and much cheaper than getting a "pro").

Answer (score 3):

Best bet would be to have some one come in and cut it for you. Then you could take care of the demo of the half you don't need. This will result in the cleanest possible division.

Edit
You may also be able to rent the saw and cut it on your own. I love to DIY things, but this seems like something I would have a pro do.